# When to use Static site generator?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, frontend, nuxt.js, jamstack

I have a web application that has login and role-based contents etc. which is created in nuxt (framework for vue)using universal mode .currently it is SSR(server-side rendering) app but Is it correct if convert it into static site using nuxt generate command ?

FYI:- I have tried running nuxt generate , it generates appropriate pages inside dist but my concern is inside each HTML files, only CSS is there and script tag. I understand i cannot statically generate contents for each page since it's based on users.knowing that is it correct if I go with SSG or does it kills its purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Avoid SSG for sites with content that changes often(dynamic) for logged in user.

**Update:-**

Lot of great sites out there for helping developers new to this, such as

1. https://jamstack.org/
2. https://explorers.netlify.com/

At the end, its way of generating html for each routes with contents at build time(some new methods also being worked on by netlify and vercel for improving build time for big jamstack sites) and once user visits home page, its html served and js kicks in and does SPA part for further navigation instead of full page refresh + interactivity